# How do lawyers determine when the preconditions for a contract have been met?

Tags: contract-law, new-york-state

There is a contract with four preconditions, of which the failure of any ONE is sufficient to void the contract.

Clearing the four preconditions requires the execution of ten documents, involving the actions/signatures of ten people. In theory, this could mean up to 100 executions, although it's more like 60-70, because while every person has to execute at least one document, not all ten persons have to execute all ten documents.

How do lawyers keep track of which documents have been executed, and which preconditions have been fulfilled? Do they use a grid or tallying system for this purpose? Are there "best practices" in record-keeping for many of the subject matters?

Answer (score 5):

We hire very good paralegals, explain to them what we are trying to achieve, and let them use common sense and the good organizational skills that got them hired to figure it out.

(Really, I once had a part-time assistant in my law office who had a full time job doing essentially what you describe over and over again. This is a classic transactional paralegal task.)

Comment: And what happens when the paralegals (or someone else doesn't do their job, and the lawyers falsely certify that a precondition has been met, when it hasn't.

Comment: @Libra The lawyers get sued for malpractice and after long and agonizing lawsuits and/or arbitration proceedings pay out big settlements. Another lawyer I work with won a case like that against a big law firm. There are some tasks for which lawyers are responsible even when they add little or no value to it.